# selecting values from a df based on multiple percentages from a different dataframe

Tags: r

I am trying to store values from one df into a new dataframe based on percentages from another df.

```
df1

   "seq"  "loc"  "ball" "square" "triangle"
1    abcd   b      65      12        9
2    abcd   a      0       75        0
3    ght5   a      5       10        25
4    dfsf   b      12      9         75

df2

    "Type"    "n"    "n/2"    "1/n" 
1    ball      10     50       10
2    square    9      55.5     11.1
3    triangle  6      50       16.6`
```

I want to store the "seq" and "loc" by "Type" in a manner that lets me know if it is present above (>=) the "n/2" value or below (<=) the "1/n" value for it's type.

```
output df3

     "seq" "loc" "ball" "square" "triangle"
1    abcd   b     True    NA       False
2    abcd   a     False   True     False
3    ght5   a     False   False    NA
4    dfsf   b     NA      False    True`
```

I used True/NA/False to indicate >=/between/<=, but it could be anything really. I just need a way to differentiate the two qualifiers. Ultimately I will be selecting any "seq" and "loc" that are True in one "Type" and False in all other Types.  (In the output example, the only one that would be reported in the end would be "abcd" "a" for "square."

As I've typed this out, I'm thinking I will probably start by making a duplicate of df1 to serve as df3, and then just store the new values in place of the percentages. That seems easier than selecting out everything and making a new table? After that, I'm not sure where to go.

EDIT: 
Currently toying with this, but not having luck with it storing a value in the dataframe.

```
df3 <- df1
for(i in seq_len(nrow(df2)))
{
df3[, df2$Type[i]] <- 
sapply(1:length(df2$Type), 
   function(y) sapply(df3[, df2$Type][,y], 
                 function(x) ifelse(x < df2[y, c("1/n")], "1", 
                             ifelse(x > df2[y, c("n/2")], "3", "2")) ))
}
```

EDIT: (Adding dput(head) of df1 and df2)

```
df1
structure(list(Seq = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = 
c("AAAAAACCAGTCCCAGTTCGGATTG", 
"AAAAAACCAGTCTCAGTTCGGATTG", "AAAAAACCGGTCACAGTTCAGATTG"), class = 
"factor"), 
loc = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("b", 
"t"), class = "factor"), Ball = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Cat = c(0, 
0, 0, 16.6666666666667, 16.6666666666667), Square = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0), Water = c(0, 0, 0, 33.3333333333333, 33.3333333333333
)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), vars = c("Seq", "loc"), drop = TRUE, indices = 
list(
0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), group_sizes = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
biggest_group_size = 1L, labels = structure(list(
Seq = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = 
c("AAAAAACCAGTCCCAGTTCGGATTG", 
"AAAAAACCAGTCTCAGTTCGGATTG", "AAAAAACCGGTCACAGTTCAGATTG"), class = 
"factor"), 
loc = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("b", 
"t"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame", 
vars = c("Seq", 
"loc"), drop = TRUE))

df2
dput(head(df2))
structure(list(Type = c("Ball", "Cat", "Square", "Water"), n = c(4L, 
6L, 3L, 6L), `n/2` = c(50, 50, 66.6666666666667, 50), `1/n` = c(25, 
16.6666666666667, 33.3333333333333, 16.6666666666667)), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dput`s you provided:

```
df1 <- structure(list(Seq = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = 
                                 c("AAAAAACCAGTCCCAGTTCGGATTG", 
                                   "AAAAAACCAGTCTCAGTTCGGATTG", "AAAAAACCGGTCACAGTTCAGATTG"), class = 
                                 "factor"), 
               loc = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("b", 
                                                                 "t"), class = "factor"), Ball = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Cat = c(0, 
                                                                                                                           0, 0, 16.6666666666667, 16.6666666666667), Square = c(0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                 0, 0, 0, 0), Water = c(0, 0, 0, 33.3333333333333, 33.3333333333333
                                                                                                                                                                                 )), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                       "tbl", "data.frame"), vars = c("Seq", "loc"), drop = TRUE, indices = 
            list(
              0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), group_sizes = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
          biggest_group_size = 1L, labels = structure(list(
            Seq = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = 
                              c("AAAAAACCAGTCCCAGTTCGGATTG", 
                                "AAAAAACCAGTCTCAGTTCGGATTG", "AAAAAACCGGTCACAGTTCAGATTG"), class = 
                              "factor"), 
            loc = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("b", 
                                                              "t"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame", 
            vars = c("Seq", 
                     "loc"), drop = TRUE))


df2 <- structure(list(Type = c("Ball", "Cat", "Square", "Water"), n = c(4L, 
                                                                 6L, 3L, 6L), `n/2` = c(50, 50, 66.6666666666667, 50), `1/n` = c(25, 
                                                                                                                                 16.6666666666667, 33.3333333333333, 16.6666666666667)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                       -4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

The code would not work correctly before for a reason unknown to me but having to do with the `class` of the data frame objects. Here, I convert to `data.frame` and then the `sapply` code works fine. The answer:

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 <- as.data.frame(df1)
df2 <- as.data.frame(df2)

df3 <- sapply(1:length(df2$Type), 
       function(y) sapply(df1[, df2$Type][,y], 
                          function(x) ifelse(x < df2[y, c("1/n")], "1", 
                                             ifelse(x > df2[y, c("n/2")], "3", 
                                                    "2")) ))

df3 <- df3 %>% as_data_frame %>% 
  setNames(df2$Type) %>% 
  add_column(Seq = df1[,c("Seq")], loc = df1[,c("loc")], .before = 1)

df3
# A tibble: 5 x 6
  Seq                       loc   Ball  Cat   Square Water
  <fct>                     <fct> <chr> <chr> <chr>  <chr>
1 AAAAAACCAGTCCCAGTTCGGATTG t     1     1     1      1    
2 AAAAAACCAGTCTCAGTTCGGATTG b     1     1     1      1    
3 AAAAAACCAGTCTCAGTTCGGATTG t     1     1     1      1    
4 AAAAAACCGGTCACAGTTCAGATTG b     1     2     1      2    
5 AAAAAACCGGTCACAGTTCAGATTG t     1     2     1      2
```

Comment: I wasn't able to get yours to function as is with my data set like it does with yours. I edited my post above to show what I am working with now.  I inserted your block into the for loop. But my output is filling every data point with a 1.

Comment: @Steve There's no need to use your `for` loop. The apply family of functions is a vectorized version of looping. You just run the code I gave you after changing the data frame specific values. It would be best if you provided a `dput` of your data sets and I can change the code to suit your specific problem.

Comment: Will the head() that i added above work?  using dput on df2 gets ugly. (a few hundred thousand rows.)

Comment: @Steve Use `dput(head(df))`.

Comment: I changed my edit in the question to have the dput(head) outputs. I also had to change a portion in my code that was causing my percents to be characters instead of numeric. Unfortunately that didn't solve my issue. The block you wrote only seems to be running for the first row. I've been attempting to alter it by including an addition sapply statement, but that hasn't been going well.

Comment: @Steve You need to actually run `dput` on your data frames and post the output. It will provide the data in a format that will allow me to easily import it. The output should like something like this: `structure(list(a = c(1, 2, 3), b = c(1, 2, 3)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))`.

Comment: Fixed, I had the parentheses wrong.  dput(head)(df) instead of dput(head(df))

Comment: @Steve That `dput` really helped. It had something to do with the `class` of the data frames. I don't know how important it is to you to have the data frames in `tbl_df` format, but after I converted them using `as.data.frame` the `sapply` code worked as it should have. I also had to change the column names. The code should be ready to go after converting to `base::data.frame`.

Comment: Thanks!  It takes 2.45 minutes to make it through my table.  Is there an easy way to make it do the sapply and have the output look like the original table? Or do I just need to copy the data from df3 back into df1 and overwrite the original values?

Comment: @Steve Added another line after. In the final data frame, characters we created by way of sapply must still be turned into factors if that's what you want.

Comment: You sir are my hero!  Thank you!  If you're bored, I'll keep throwing questions at you.

Comment: I went ahead and started a new question since I'm heading out of the office for a few days.  Thanks for all the help!  [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53841449/determining-if-one-value-occurs-once-in-a-row-of-columns-but-a-second-value-doe]

Comment: @Steve No problem. Happy to help.