# Determining if one value occurs once in a row of columns, but a second value doesn't occur at all

Tags: r, sapply

Probably a terrible title, but I have a table of qualifiers stored as "1", "2", and "3". What I'm trying to do is is look in each row (approximately 300,000 rows, but variable.) and determine where a single "3" occurs, (if it occurs more than once, I am not interested in it) and the rest of the columns in that row have a "1", and return that to a list. (The number of columns and column names change based on the input files.)

Instinctively I want to attempt this by doing nested for loops that index the row count, and then the column count, then some function that looks for one "3" and no "2"'s. --which likely means the preferred way would be some apply function correct?

Another though was to total the number of columns, add 2, and then sum the row while having a qualifier that no 2's can be in the row. But that seemed pretty complicated.

```
df1
  seq                        loc   Ball   Cat   Square   Water
1 AAAAAACCAGTCCCAGTTCGGATTG  t       3     1      1       1  
2 AAAAAACCAGTCTCAGTTCGGATTG  b       1     1      3       3
3 AAAAAACCAGTCTCAGTTCGGATTG  t       1     3      2       1
4 AAAAAACCGGTCACAGTTCAGATTG  b       1     1      1       2
5 AAAAAACCGGTCACAGTTCAGATTG  t       1     1      3       1


Expected Ouput:
  seq                        loc     Group   
1 AAAAAACCAGTCCCAGTTCGGATTG  t       Ball    
2 AAAAAACCGGTCACAGTTCAGATTG  t       Square 


dput of df1:
structure(list(seq = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = 
c("AAAAAACCAGTCCCAGTTCGGATTG", 
"AAAAAACCAGTCTCAGTTCGGATTG", "AAAAAACCGGTCACAGTTCAGATTG"), class = 
"factor"), 
loc = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("b", 
"t"), class = "factor"), Ball = c("3", "1", "1", "1", "1"
), Cat = c("1", "1", "3", "1", "1"), Square = c("1", "3", 
"2", "1", "3"), Water = c("1", "3", "1", "2", "1")), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a solution without tidyverse and even *apply functions. First, let's convert those four columns to integers:

```
cols <- 3:6
df1[cols] <- lapply(df1[cols], as.integer)
```

Then

```
df <- df1[rowSums(df1[cols]) == (3 + length(cols) - 1) & rowSums(df1[cols] == 3) == 1, ]
df$Group <- names(df)[cols][which(t(df[cols]) == 3, arr.ind = TRUE)[, 1]]
df
# A tibble: 2 x 7
#   seq                       loc    Ball   Cat Square Water Group 
#   <fct>                     <fct> <int> <int>  <int> <int> <chr> 
# 1 AAAAAACCAGTCCCAGTTCGGATTG t         3     1      1     1 Ball  
# 2 AAAAAACCGGTCACAGTTCAGATTG t         1     1      3     1 Square
```

In the first line I select the right rows with two conditions: there has to be only one element equal to 3 in those `cols` columns (`rowSums(df1[cols] == 3) == 1`) and the total sum of the row has to be `3 + length(cols) - 1`. Then in the second row I check which columns have `3` and pick corresponding names of `df` as values for `Group`.

Comment: Thanks! I may need to clarify that "3" can occur multiple times in a row of values as well, and I am only interested in when it occurs only once. I will edit my demo set to reflect that.    (I just checked and I accounted for that combination in the demo set. - But when I run your code against my dataset, it returns any sequence that has 3's and 1's, even if it has multiple 3's.)

Comment: @Steve, that's what I thought. There are two 3's in the second row but it's not selected.

Comment: I just edited my response above. I am getting returns for rows with multiple 3's. I am also only getting results for the first 4 columns. (my actual dataset has anywhere from 7-15 columns.)  Thank you for the help though! I look forward to working on this more Friday.

Comment: @Steve, did you adjust the `cols` variable? To those columns that we should be looking at (those 7-15).

Comment: @IceCreamToucan, the question says that only 1, 2, 3 are possible values, so it's fine, just as like your alternative is.

Comment: @Vainora, I didn't change the cols variable!  Could I put a function in there that counts the columns from 3:end?

Comment: @Steve, sure, I left it like this because it wasn't clear what the structure of your dataset is. `cols <- 3:ncol(df1)` may indeed be what you need.

Comment: @icecreamtoucan  there are only 1's, 2's, and 3's.  So if you exclude 2's, the row totals can only be the number of columns plus 2 for the ones I'm looking for.      Posting from my phone, sorry for the jumble.

Comment: Still working on this. I am trying to figure out why, but the output is incorrect. I am getting Seq's with the wrong group  when I look back at df1 to verify.

Comment: `df$Group <- names(df)[cols][which(df[cols] == 3, arr.ind = TRUE)[, 2]]`  This block is where the problem is occuring, it is assigning the groups incorrectly.

Comment: @Steve, is everything the same in your real data set? Possible values still 1, 2, 3, still looking for rows with one 3 and the rest 1's? `which(df[cols] == 3, arr.ind = TRUE)[, 2]` gets a vector of columns from `cols` corresponding to their groups and then `names(df)[cols]` is a vector of group names that is used.. Doesn't look wrong. Looking at `names(df)[cols]` helps to verify that `cols` is set correctly.

Comment: Everything is correct. It's sorting them alphabetically before applying them to the rows. Hmm

Comment: @Steve, I'm sorry, it was indeed my mistake. `which` sorts its results by the second column, not the first one. See the update, it should be fine now.

Comment: Like a charm! Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I often use the basic `apply` when doing rowwise calculations. You could do something with the actual `dplyr::rowwise` if you wanted a tidyverse solution. Here's just using base R:

```
filter_on = apply(X = df1[3:6], 
                  MARGIN = 1, 
                  FUN = function(x){sum(x == 3) == 1 & sum(x == 1) == 3})
df1 = df1[filter_on,]

columns = colnames(df1)[3:6]

df1$Group = unlist(apply(X = df1[3:6], 
                         MARGIN = 1,
                         FUN = function(x){columns[x == 3]}))
```

Comment: I am working on using this as well, but am currently winding up with an empty table as the output.

Comment: That probably means that `filter_on` is returning `FALSE` for every row.  Try `table(filter_on)`. Might want to make sure you have the right columns selected in the `apply` statement and that all the columns you're checking are numeric.

Comment: I'm confused at what you mean by use `table(filter_on)`. I've tried my hand at what I thought you meant, but I get errors because it thinks i'm trying to call a function named df1.  The `filter_on` does look to be all FALSE.

Comment: @Steve Yeah that's what I wanted to know. When you set `filter_on = apply(...)` you're making a vector. You're then filtering the data according to the which rows of your data frame are `TRUE`. If they're all `FALSE`, the data frame will have no rows which seems to be what's happening. Without seeing your data, it's hard to know why it's failing but I suspect that either you have the wrong columns selected, the column types are not all numeric, or there genuinely are no rows that fit the description.

Answer (score 3):

Just to show an alternative where we work with data in long format instead of row-wise. Here, using `data.table` functions:

```
library(data.table)
d <- melt(setDT(df1), id.vars = c("seq", "loc"))
d[d[ , .I[sum(value == 3) == 1 & !any(value == 2)], by = .(seq, loc)]$V1][value == 3]
#                          seq loc variable value
# 1: AAAAAACCAGTCCCAGTTCGGATTG   t     Ball     3
# 2: AAAAAACCGGTCACAGTTCAGATTG   t   Square     3
```

---

`melt` data to long format using 'sec' and 'loc' as id variables. If the combination of 'sec' and 'loc' are not unique identifiers of rows, create a unique row index (e.g. `ri := 1:.N`).

For each 'sec' and 'loc' (`by = .(seq, loc)`; i.e. for each row in original data), create a logical vector for the desired condition: one 3 and no 2 per row (`sum(value == 3) == 1 & !any(value == 2)`). Grab corresponding row indexes (`.I`). The indexes, auto-named 'V1', are then used to subset 'd'.

Finally, select rows where 'value' equals 3 (`[value == 3]`).

Answer (score 1):

Putting in an extra version. This only covers the row selection.

```
#create vector of wanted column names
cols <- c("Ball", "Cat", "Square", "Water")
#make values numeric
df1[, cols] <- df1[, cols] %>% mutate_if(is.character, as.numeric)

#filter rows
df1[which((rowSums(df1[, cols]) == (length(cols)+2) ) & (rowSums(df1[, cols] == 2) == 0)),]

                        seq loc Ball Cat Square Water
1 AAAAAACCAGTCCCAGTTCGGATTG   t    3   1      1     1
5 AAAAAACCGGTCACAGTTCAGATTG   t    1   1      3     1
```

Looks like the `apply` version is fastest of the first three posts, but not by much.

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
which = df1[which((rowSums(df1[, cols]) == (length(cols)+2) ) & (rowSums(df1[, cols] == 2) == 0)),],
filter = df1[rowSums(df1[cols]) == (3 + length(cols) - 1) & rowSums(df1[cols] == 3) == 1, ],
apply = df1[apply(X = df1[3:6], 
          MARGIN = 1, 
          FUN = function(x){sum(x == 3) == 1 & sum(x == 1) == 3}),]
)

Unit: microseconds
   expr     min       lq     mean  median       uq      max neval cld
  which 429.043 436.4665 446.2817 445.811 451.3140  493.553   100   a
 filter 429.555 435.5715 447.8151 440.307 449.2670  724.202   100   a
  apply 339.958 346.9975 435.0437 351.222 362.2295 8141.819   100   a
```

Comment: Using only that one condition is not enough: having (2,2,1,1) would be a false match.

Comment: @JuliusVainora Should take that into account now.

Answer (score 1):

My solution was a take off of @Julius Vainora.. Mine is more convoluted but I used `match()` and added an index column.

```
DF$index <- seq.int(nrow(DF))
col_names <- names(DF)[3:ncol(DF)]

DF$Group <- col_names[which(DF[cols] == 3, arr.ind = TRUE)[,2][
  DF$index[match(
    DF$index, which(
       DF[cols] == 3, arr.ind = TRUE[,1])]]]
```